# PHP call Metodo and redirect to view

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I have a form with a input type text and a submit buttom like so:

```
<form method="post">            
    <input type="submit"value="Emitir Voucher" class="btn btn-success" style="float: right" />
        <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
             <input type="text" name="friendName" style="width: 100%;" />
        </div>​
</form>
```

I need to when I click my button send to a metodo the name=friendName and more 3 parameters and then when finished doing stuff in the metodo redirect to a success `page.php`.
How can I go about this. I have allready tried to put in my `action="success.php"` but did not work. Can I call a metodo and send parameters to mymetodo from my form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach to use an `action` in your form is correct. The file given there should then contain the method you want to run, like this:

```
//success.php:
<?php
method(); //just make method call the first and only statement in your file

method() {
    //Do your stuff here, e. g. access $_POST['name'], etc. But see below because of security!

    //Now, redirect to page.php
    //Make sure there is no output above this line!
    header('Location: page.php');
}
?>
```

Please note, that you should always check every variable passed by the user, at least using [`FILTER_INPUT`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-input.php). You could also look around for a framework (like Symfony, CakePHP, ...) that makes the whole stuff easier for you.

**Edit (according to comment):**

You can send multiple parameters at the same time. Just use multiple `<input>` tags in your form. If you want the user to fill them in, use sth. like `<input type="text" name="userInput">`. If the value is not to be given by the user, you can use `<input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" value="hiddenValue">`.

You would then access these values in your `success.php` using `$_POST['userInput']` and `$_POST['hiddenInput']`. You can choose the content of the `name` and `value` attribute as you wish.

Additionally, you could also send the "hidden" values within the URL, therefore avoiding the `<input type="hidden" ...` elements. The URL would then look like this: `success.php?hiddenInput=hiddenValue&otherHiddenInput=otherHiddenValue...`. The first input must be preceded by a `?`, all the following ones by a `&`. This would be the URL you set as `action` in your form.

If you set your form method to `get`, all values submitted by `input` tags are treated this way, including `<input type="hidden" ...`. Afterwards, you can access them by using `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

Please be careful about which variables are submitted via URL (`get`). Security relevant data should not be handled this way. Please also remember the `FILTER_INPUT` function for security reasons.

Comment: Hi. Is it possible to send more than one parameter at the same time. I ask this question because I need to send a total of 5 paramateres. This first paramater is friendName and the rest are in the url.

Comment: I edited my post according to that. As you can see, input given via URL can be handled reading `$_GET`, the rest using `$_POST`.

Comment: Hi. Thank's Worked Fine.